How can I Align a Flat Surface to Three Vertices?
I have a grid object (or flat surface) and 3 vertices. I want to align (move or reorient) the surface to 3 points/vertices so the 3 points should be on the surface. How can I do this?

First fill in a face into the 3 vertices so you have a face you can snap to. Then under the Snapping tool options, select the following options:

Now you can select the Grid and simply grab with G and drag it onto the triangle. It will snap onto it.


Just a quick note: when Align Rotation to Target is activated it is not necessary to enable Snapping for Rotate as well. The plane will be rotated automatically. The Rotate option is only to make Snapping available when you are manually using the Rotate tool or R to rotate the object (but it does not align the rotation to the target).

@GordonBrinkmann thank you for the clarification! :)
